# radial percentage bar in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Bear with me as I'm really new to Canvas and just experimenting.

I am trying to make a radial percentage bar in html Canvas with animation that makes it go round starting at 1 angle and ending at the defined end angle (it is not a circle it is like a pie with a chunk taken out)

I've put the angles at 45 degrees away from the bottom just using trial and error with the figures.  What I am trying to do is make the inner arc animate round based on what percentage it is defined at but i can't find the right figures to "rotate" it.

Also I need to be able to change the colour of the inner arc.

Another thing I was struggling with was how to take that outside static bar out of the animation without breaking it.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
```

SCRIPT:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var x = canvas.width / 2;
 var y = canvas.height / 2;
 var radius = 75;
 var endPercent = 100;
 var curPerc = 0.75 * Math.PI;
 var counterClockwise = false;
 var circ = Math.PI * 2;
 var quart = Math.PI / 2;
 var startAngle = 0.75 * Math.PI;
 var endAngle = 2.25 * Math.PI;

 context.lineWidth = 10;
 context.strokeStyle = '#ad2323';


 function animate(current) {
     context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     context.beginPath();
     context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
     context.stroke();
     context.closePath();

     context.beginPath();
     context.arc(x, y, 50, 0, ((circ) * current) - 0.5 * Math.PI, false);
     context.stroke();
     context.closePath();
     curPerc++;
     if (curPerc < endPercent) {
         requestAnimationFrame(function () {
             animate(curPerc / 100)
         });
     }
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/susannalarsen/Lnav9w49/

Comment: Sorry it isn't very clear.  What I am trying to do is get the inner circle to start at the same point as where the outer circle starts and then moving it to 100% would be be the right hand side cut off point at the same position as the outer circle

Comment: Okay, think I've gotcha - time for more coffee. Just set the stroke style before you do the drawing (ctx.stroke()) Here 'tis: http://jsfiddle.net/Lnav9w49/2/

Comment: so rather than 0% to a 100% going round in a full 360 degree angle like a circle it would start and end at the same angles shows by outer circle

Comment: ahh yes that is great for the colour! I am still learning the basics at the minute

Comment: Maybe with a little refactoring you could see things more clearly : http://jsfiddle.net/Lnav9w49/3/

Comment: the structuring is much better. I'm just still struggling to rotate that arc round. I can only manage to do it by changing the percentage to start at 45.

Comment: I'm still unsure about your idea. Is it closer ? http://jsfiddle.net/Lnav9w49/4/

Comment: yes thats it. same starting and end points more or less except filling in the opposite way. So going from the left and filling up to the right. I tried doing the anticlockwise thing but it messed up on the percentages

Comment: Very easy : start from startPercentage and go to currentPercentage. http://jsfiddle.net/Lnav9w49/6/

Comment: brilliant! that was exactly what I wanted. Do you want to put that as an answer and I will choose it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some refactoring, the answer looks like :

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var parameters = {
    center: { x: canvas.width / 2,
        y: canvas.height / 2
    },
    innerRadius: 50,
    outerRadius: 75,
    innerColor: '#ad2323',
    outerColor: '#DE4040',
    startPercent: 45,
    endPercent: 100,
    lineWidth: 10
};


//
var curPerc = parameters.startPercent;
animate();

// ----------------------------------------

function animate(current) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    drawInnerCircle(curPerc);

    drawOuterCircle();

    curPerc++;
    if (curPerc < parameters.endPercent) {
        requestAnimationFrame(function () {
            animate(curPerc);
        });
    }
}

function drawInnerCircle(curr) {
    var startAngle = percentToAngle(parameters.startPercent);
    var endAngle = percentToAngle(curr);
    context.lineWidth = parameters.lineWidth;
    context.strokeStyle = parameters.innerColor;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(parameters.center.x, parameters.center.y, parameters.innerRadius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
    context.stroke();
}

function drawOuterCircle() {    
    var startAngle = percentToAngle(parameters.startPercent);
    var endAngle = percentToAngle(parameters.endPercent);
    context.lineWidth = parameters.lineWidth;
    context.strokeStyle = parameters.outerColor;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(parameters.center.x, parameters.center.y, parameters.outerRadius,  startAngle, endAngle, false);
    context.stroke();
}

function percentToAngle(perc) {
    return perc * 2 * Math.PI / 100;
}
```

```css
   body {
       margin: 0px;
       padding: 0px;
       background: #f1ecec;
   }
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
```